# PHP version update issue

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, web-hosting

I Tried to update my PHP version located on Hostgator. Actually, I'm using but PHP 5.0 and WordPress is requiring at least the PHP 7 version.

After doing that, through the c-panel, my website went down.

This is the message that I received:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

I was obliged to roll-back so that it works again.

Please can you help me solve that problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the error message mentioned, the mysql extension was not loaded.   You need to install it seperatly. You have mentioned that wordpress want php7. So you have installed an new OS and than tried to installed a new version of wordpress? Or do you tried to installed your old version first and update to the new version of wordpress later? The question has following background: There are two extension for connection to mysql for a while ( mysql and mysqli ) mysql is deprecated for some time and since php 7.4 only mysqli is avaible.

Comment: Dear Thomas, I have not install any software. That isssue is probably on the host side. My host is Hostgator and When I simply applied the guidelines given by them and it didn't work. In fact, My Php version actually is 5.4 and On the WordPress dashboard, they are asking me to upgrade as soon as to phph 7.1

Answer (score 0):

The php mysql api is deprecated. It's kaput --- going away -- not to be used, finito.

If you have a modern version of PHP (> 5.6) then Wordpress should automatically switch to make use of mysqli. That should be your first attempt.

If you can not update your php, rather than attempting to resurrect something that php no longer supports, just patch your wordpress: http://wordpress.org/plugins/mysqli/